# Modificar registros en varias columnas en un CSV, utilizando sólo Python

Tags: python, csv

Tengo un archivo .csv que posee ciertas columnas que en sus registros posee el formato número y letra. Por ejemplo, existe una columna que se llama **peso** y sus datos registrados son 90 kg, 65 kg, y así cada registro de la columna. Otro ejemplo, columna **altura**, 170 cm, 165 cm, entre otros. El tamaño del .csv es de 11 mil registros por 100 columnas, aproximadamente.

Ya planteada la realidad, lo que requiero hacer es, utilizando **Python**, eliminar el *"kg"* y el *"cm"* de los registros, en cada columna ya indicada, para sólo quedar con los datos numéricos con los cuales necesito trabajar, ya que en la columna no hay otras unidades de medidas que las indicadas, por lo cual no es necesario guardar la unidad en alguna parte.

No sé como proceder.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado hasta ahora? si ya has probado algo, te sugiero que lo agregues a tu pregunta así tu pregunta será mejor recibida por la comunidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

si los valores del archivo tienen la misma estructura (`"xxx cm"`, `"xxx kg"`)
puedes usar pandas para eliminar los últimos dos caracteres de la columnas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv")
df["peso"] = df["peso"].str[:-2].astype(float)
df["altura"] = df["altura"].str[:-2].astype(float)
```

lo que hace ese codigo es tomar todos los valores de las columnas `peso` y `altura`, convertirlos a `string` para eliminar los ultimos dos caracteres `[:-2]` y despues convertirlos a `float` con el metodo `astype` de pandas.

pero eso suponiendo que todos los valores tienen "cm" y "kg" porque de no ser así eliminara información o podrá arrojar error, igual podría servirte

Answer (score 1):

No te sirve con reemplazar el 'cm' y el 'kg' en cualquier editor de texto?

De no ser así, te pongo otra opción en la que podrás poner en un diccionario las columnas y los textos que quieres que desaparezcan:

```
import pandas as pd

datos = pd.read_csv('archivo.csv')
quitar = {'peso': ' kg', 'altura': ' cm'}

for q in quitar:
    datos[q] = datos[q].map(lambda x: x.strip(quitar[q])).astype(float)
```

Con esto en la variable 'datos' tendras un DataFrame de pandas ya limpio.

Si lo que quieres es obtener un nuevo csv ya limpio para trabajar:

```
with open('archivo.csv', 'r') as f:
    texto = [linea.replace(' cm', '').replace(' kg', '') for linea in f.readlines()]

with open('archivo2.csv', 'w') as f:
    [f.write(linea) for linea in texto]
```